# Writing Stored Procedure output to file using SqlInfoMessageEventHandler

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that prints to Messages in SQL Server, I am writing a C# Application to call the stored procedure and write the output to a file.

I am using the `SqlInfoMessageEventHandler` to handle the output being in message, however the output, in this case the result variable is not being written to the file.

Below is my full code for this application.

```
public class SProc
{
    public static string result;

    static void Conn_InfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        result = (e.Message);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string ClassName = "";
        string TableName = "";

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Class Name: ");
        ClassName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Table Name: ");
        TableName = Console.ReadLine();

        var filePath = @"C:\Temp\%name%.txt".Replace("%name%", ClassName); 

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionVal"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.mainproc", connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "dbo.mainproc";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableName", "model");

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                connection.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(Conn_InfoMessage);
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                */Outputs just fine*/
                sw.WriteLine($"[Table({TableName})]");
                 */Returns Empty in text file */
                sw.WriteLine($"{result}")
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to set the InfoMessage handler *before* you ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: @AlexK. Thank you so much!

Comment: Do not use [addwithvalue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)